# power bi report server scheduled refresh error

Tags: error-handling, timeout, powerbi, refresh

Does anyone know how could I find out which tables cause timeout expired Error?
I got this error:
SessionId: 482ce55f-624a....,  Timeout expired. The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the operation.

Answer (score 0):

I'm getting this error too for a scheduled refresh on PBIRS from a CSV. I'm still working on eliminating the problem. If it is an option, you could 'Edit' the report you have on the report server in Desktop - and prevent the tables from doing refreshes and then test it again by process of elimination. That's my plan at the moment, and I've started with the simplest table with no queries.

Comment: could you find the solution?